# C++ Builder Function error [bcc32 - Ambiguity error] inside dll file

Tags: dll, error-handling, c++builder

I am creating a currency converter Win32 program in Embarcadero C++Builder. I wrote a function for transforming date from format specified on user PC to `YYYY-MM-DD` format. I need that part because of API settings.

When I have this function inside my project it works fine, but I need to have that function inside a DLL.

This is how my code looks like:

```
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused
#include <SysUtils.hpp>

extern DELPHI_PACKAGE void __fastcall DecodeDate(const System::TDateTime DateTime, System::Word &Year, System::Word &Month, System::Word &Day);

extern "C" UnicodeString __declspec (dllexport) __stdcall datum(TDateTime dat) {
    Word dan, mjesec, godina;
    UnicodeString datum, datum_dan, datum_mjesec, datum_godina;
    DecodeDate(dat, godina, mjesec, dan);

    if (dan<=9 && mjesec<=9) {
        datum_dan="0"+IntToStr(dan);
        datum_mjesec="0"+IntToStr(mjesec);
    }

    if (dan<=9 && mjesec>9) {
        datum_dan="0"+IntToStr(dan);
        datum_mjesec=IntToStr(mjesec);
    }

    if (dan>9 && mjesec<=9) {
        datum_dan=IntToStr(dan);
        datum_mjesec="0"+IntToStr(mjesec);
    }

    if (dan>9 && mjesec>9) {
        datum_dan=IntToStr(dan);
        datum_mjesec=IntToStr(mjesec);
    }

    datum_godina=IntToStr(godina);

    return datum_godina+"-"+datum_mjesec+"-"+datum_dan;

}

extern "C" int _libmain(unsigned long reason)
{
    return 1;
}
    `
```

I've included `SysUtils.hpp` and declared `DecodeDate()` function, without those lines I have a million errors. But with code looking like this, I am getting this error, which I can't get rid of:

```
[bcc32 Error] File1.cpp(30): E2015 Ambiguity between '_fastcall System::Sysutils::DecodeDate(const System::TDateTime,unsigned short &,unsigned short &,unsigned short &) at c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\include\windows\rtl\System.SysUtils.hpp:3466' and '_fastcall DecodeDate(const System::TDateTime,unsigned short &,unsigned short &,unsigned short &) at File1.cpp:25'
  Full parser context
    File1.cpp(27): parsing: System::UnicodeString __stdcall datum(System::TDateTime)
```

Can you help me to get rid of that error?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is self-explanatory.  You have two functions with the same name in scope, and the compiler doesn't know which one you want to use on line 30 because the parameters you are passing in satisfy both function declarations.

To fix the error, you can change this line:

```
DecodeDate(dat, godina, mjesec, dan);
```

To either this:

```
System::Sysutils::DecodeDate(dat, godina, mjesec, dan);
```

Or this:

```
dat.DecodeDate(&godina, &mjesec, &dan);
```

However, either way, you should get rid of your `extern` declaration for `DecodeDate()`, as it doesn't belong in this code at all.  You are not implementing `DecodeDate()` yourself, you are just using the one provided by the RTL.  There is already a declaration for `DecodeDate()` in `SysUtils.hpp`, which you are `#include`'ing in your code.  That is all the compiler needs.

Just make sure you are linking to the RTL/VCL libraries to resolve the function during the linker stage after compiling.  You should have enabled VCL support when you created the DLL project.  If you didn't, recreate your project and enable it.

BTW, there is a MUCH easier way to implement your function logic - instead of manually pulling apart the `TDateTime` and reconstituting its components, just use the [`SysUtils::FormatDateTime()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FormatDateTime) function or the [`TDateTime::FormatString()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TDateTime.FormatString) method instead, eg:

```
UnicodeString __stdcall datum(TDateTime dat)
{
    return FormatDateTime(_D("yyyy'-'mm'-'dd"), dat);
}
```

```
UnicodeString __stdcall datum(TDateTime dat)
{
    return dat.FormatString(_D("yyyy'-'mm'-'dd"));
}
```

That being said, this code is still wrong, because it is not safe to pass non-POD types, like `UnicodeString`, over the DLL boundary like you are doing.  You need to re-think your DLL function design to use only interop-safe POD types.  In this case, change your function to either:

- take a `wchar_t*` as input from the caller, and just fill in the memory block with the desired characters.  Let the caller allocate the actual buffer and pass it in to your DLL for populating:

  ```
  #pragma hdrstop
  #pragma argsused
  #include <SysUtils.hpp>

  extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall datum(double dat, wchar_t *buffer, int buflen)
  {
      UnicodeString s = FormatDateTime(_D("yyyy'-'mm'-'dd"), dat);
      if (!buffer) return s.Length() + 1;
      StrLCopy(buffer, s.c_str(), buflen-1);
      return StrLen(buffer);
  }

  extern "C" int _libmain(unsigned long reason)
  {
      return 1;
  }
  ```

  ```
  wchar_t buffer[12] = {};
  datum(SomeDateValueHere, buffer, 12);
  // use buffer as needed...
  ```

  ```
  int len = datum(SomeDateValueHere, NULL, 0);
  wchar_t *buffer = new wchar_t[len];
  int len = datum(SomeDateValueHere, buffer, len);
  // use buffer as needed...
  delete[] buffer;
  ```
- allocate a `wchar_t[]` buffer to hold the desired characters, and then return a `wchar_t*` pointer to that buffer to the caller.  Then export a second function that the caller can pass the returned `wchar_t*` back to you so you can free it correctly.

  ```
  #pragma hdrstop
  #pragma argsused
  #include <SysUtils.hpp>

  extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) wchar_t* __stdcall datum(double dat)
  {
      UnicodeString s = FormatDateTime("yyyy'-'mm'-'dd", dat);
      wchar_t* buffer = new wchar_t[s.Length()+1];
      StrLCopy(buffer, s.c_str(), s.Length());
      return buffer;
  }

  extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall free_datum(wchar_t *dat)
  {
      delete[] dat;
  }

  extern "C" int _libmain(unsigned long reason)
  {
      return 1;
  }
  ```

  ```
  wchar_t *buffer = datum(SomeDateValueHere);
  // use buffer as needed...
  free_datum(buffer);
  ```

Comment: I tried without this extern delcaration with SysUtils.hpp, and without .hpp with extern declaration, either way I can't compile it...Without __declspec(dllexport) my dll builds fine, but with that I can't get rid of an error. With code like this I have 1 error, with some alteration I've done I have 5-10 errors. Without __declspec it works fine, but I need dllexport so I am stuck here now...

Comment: @DinoCro That is all wrong. You DO NOT need that `extern` statement. You are not implementing the actual `DecodeDate()` function yourself, you are just using the RTL's existing function. DO NOT REDECLARE THE FUNCTION!  If you are still having errors, then you are are still doing something wrong. Please edit your question to add those details.

Comment: @DinoCro: The fact that things still don't work is that you don't do exactly what the answer tells you to do. Try to understand what is being said and then follow the advice **exactly**, do not experiment with different solutions yourself. Programming is not a game of trial and error. Not following the exact advice is often a case of repeated "still doesn't work" questions in comments. Don't be a help vampire.

Comment: @DinoCro: while the following article is advice for Delphi, it applies to other languages too (e.g. not using compiler-specific types between DLL and program): [DLL dos and don'ts](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html). Read it and try to follow it.